# Facebook "Likebox" plugin is not working properly on IE8

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer-8

I am facing problem with Facebook "Likebox" plugin in IE8 browser.

When a fresh page having Facebook data loads  on IE8, It shows all business feeds but vertical scroll bar is missing. So the user is not able to read all business feeds. If i open Facebook website in the side tab and refresh my page then scroll bar displays properly.

But again if i clear the browser cache and refresh the page then same problem occurs. sometimes correct number of profile pics are also not coming in like section.

Code:

```
   <div id="fb-root">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">        
  (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
} (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
 <div class="cbox width5 facebook">
<h3 id="headerFacebook" runat="server">
    Join us on Facebook</h3>
<div class="cbox-content divfacebook" style="padding: 0; border: 0;">
    <ul class="feedlist">
        <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="<%=FacebookPageUrl %>" data-width="383" data-height="480"
            data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="false">
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

An early response will be highly appreciated.